# layer-list's color become black in android 4.1.2

Tags: android

This is the complete xml :

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/pink" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="@dimen/border_size"
            android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

What it did is simply have a pink background color with white outline. It works perfectly when i test it using android 4.2.2.

However, the pink background color always become the black color in android 4.1.2 (the outline is still white - which is working fine).

Note that i use real device (not a fan of emulator)

Please kindly help me, Thanks for your help.

Note : I've tried to clean the project, uninstall the apps.

Thanks to `@Der Golem`, this is the working - simplified code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@color/pink" />

    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/border_size"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Do you really need **2** overlayed shapes? One is enough. Just set the solid (fill) and the stroke (border) on the same shape. Moreover, make sure you have the `pink` color resource correctly defined in your colors.xml and that you **don't alter it** in code OR that you **don't have different** colors.xml in different `values` folders.

Comment: @DerGolem Thanks a lot. I change it to only use one shape and its working perfectly now. Please answer my question so i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need **2 overlayed shapes**?
**One** is just enough.

Simply, set the solid (fill) color and the stroke (border) color on the same shape.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D For those who have same problem, i post the code in the question